# Java - Spring - JDBC - Same code returning different response. How to debug?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jdbc

Same code returning different response. How to debug?
Output from aws_managed/tomcat-8 (This Docker is meant for linux - So not able to run in my windows)

```
[
    {
        "incomplete": ".58", //Without 0 before decimal
    }
]
```

Same war file deployed in local apache tomcat

```
[
    {
        "incomplete": "0.58" // with 0 before decimal

    }
]
```

I use spring jdbcTemplate and convert everything to String - irrespective of whether the column is number or String.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; ++i) {
    recordMap.put(colLabel.toLowerCase(), rs.getString(colLabel));
}
```

Any specific areas I should check.

Comment: Can you change the Locale of aws_managed/tomcat-8 ? I think this problem is due to some differences for Locale of the 2 tomcats. Otherwise you could force the "print format" of the number via Java. Add the lines of code you are running in order to get that message. Just the print.

Comment: can this have any relation with ojdbc jars?